# The arctangent is a strange floating point number

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, floating-point

I have 2 players in a game (Cod 4). I read `X`, `Y`, `Z` and store them in: `eX`, `eY` and `eZ` for enemy coordinates, and `pX`, `pY` and `pZ` for my player, then I get the `Vector` for `X` and `Z`:

```
if (eX <=  pX and  eZ < pZ) is true then
VectorX = pX - eX
VectorZ = pZ - eZ
```

Then I tried this: `Atan (VectorX/VectorZ) * 180.0f / PI` (the game uses degrees so I convert from radians), then the number I got divided by `360` but that gives me a crazy float like `5.5343434e-44`.

What does this mean, and why does it happen?

Comment: This means the answer is $0$, because of the exponential factor $10^{-44}$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what KittyL wrote in his/her comment to the question (why do people answer in comments?), atan() has returned a floating point number close to $0$. $5.5343434$e-$44$ means $5.5343434\times10^{-44}$). This is a perfectly fine result if, for example, VectorX is a small positive number and VectorZ is a large positive number.